# Implementing Socket.IO in VueJS CLI app with custom files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

Ok so in the following link, you'll find ccc-streamer-utilities.js and a folder called streamer with a stream.js file in it.

[Here's the link](https://github.com/cryptoqween/cryptoqween.github.io/tree/master/streamer)

stream.js manages websocket connections and ccc-streamer-utilites.js decorates the output and provides helper functions.

What I need to do is include the following files and utilise them within a Vue CLI app. However, I am having a lot of difficulty attempting to do this. After trying for a week and asking on reddit, here I am.

This is what the main.js file looks like. Please point me in the right direction if helping isn't something you're inclined to do.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io' //VueJS socket component
import io from 'socket.io-client' //Socket import

Vue.use(Vuetify, VueSocketIO, socket)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The component would look like this

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div> ... (socket output is determined by element classes and divs [check the two files for more information on this] so ideally, I'd have an implementation that allows me to just input the right class and id's to get the result i want) </div>
  </div>
</template>
.....
```

[Here's an implementation of the client without using VueJS that I did a few months ago while prototyping.](http://bitformatics-test.herokuapp.com/index.html)

Thank you so much for taking the time to actually help me here since I know I'm asking for a lot.

**My question:  How do I implement the utility that stream.js and ccc-streamer-utilities.js provide inside a Single File Component in VueJS?**

Comment: Do you have any errors, or something perhaps that could help us understand what the functional problem is? Can we see the server side configuration that accompanies this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't have a server-side config for this @Ohgodwhy. I built the prototype using those two files and had everything running client-side. I was hoping to be able to do this again, only with VueJS as the front-end framework. All I've been able to achieve without errors are the two imports I commented in the first code snippet. It's absolutely pathetic, I know but any sort of guidance on how to approach the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: If anyone wants to play around and see how it actually works, clone the repo and run the index.html file in /streamer/current.

Comment: @StevenB. My bad. Here's what my question is: How do I implement the utility that stream.js and ccc-streamer-utilities.js provide inside a Single File Component in VueJS?

I've already used those two files in the front end before and I've provided a link to showcase that. I know what they do and how to use them. Just can't figure out the VueJS Single File component implementation of this. The post has been edited to reflect changes

Comment: There seems to be a lot to this question.  The utilities could be reimplemented as component methods, as a mixin, or they could simply be exported and imported as needed. The stream.js looks like it'll be a bit more involved.  Typically events are setup in the `created` lifecycle method and then you can go from there.

Comment: So then if I just import socket.io-client and vue-socket.io into the component, divide stream.js into a set of methods called upon in the created lifecycle method and import the utility file in the component as well, I'll be good to go?

Does that mean I can remove the socket.io imports in the main.js folder and put them in the component instead? I read in several other places that apparently you're supposed to declare it globally in main.js, idk though